# What does an Ulam matrix look like?

Tags: matrices, set-theory

I'm trying to visualize an Ulam matrix but I"m having trouble. So it has Aleph one rows and aleph null columns? What do elements of a Ulam matrix look like?

Comment: kind of greenish purple

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It need not have $\aleph_1$ rows and $\aleph_0$ columns: one can define larger Ulam matrices. However, $(\aleph_1,\aleph_0)$-Ulam matrices are a reasonable place to start. Such a matrix is a collection of sets $A_{\alpha,n}$ for $\alpha<\omega_1$ and $n<\omega$ such that

- each $A_{\alpha,n}\subseteq\omega_1$;
- if $\alpha<\beta<\omega_1$, then $A_{\alpha,n}\cap A_{\beta,n}=\varnothing$ for each $n<\omega$; and
- for each $\alpha<\omega_1$, $\left|\omega_1\setminus\bigcup_{n<\omega}A_{\alpha,n}\right|\le\aleph_0$.

In other words, the sets in each column are pairwise disjoint, and the union of the sets in each row is almost all of $\omega_1$ — specifically, all but at most countably many elements of $\omega_1$.

It’s hard to say much more about what the sets look like: any collection satisfying all of those conditions is an Ulam matrix. You can perhaps get a little more insight by working through a proof that there actually *is* an Ulam matrix.

> For each $\xi<\omega_1$ let $f_\xi:\omega\to\omega_1$ be a function such that $\xi\subseteq\operatorname{ran}f_\xi$. For example, for each $n<\omega$ we can define $f_n$ by $f_n(k)=k$ for each $k<n$ and let $f(k)=0$ for $n<k<\omega$. If $\omega\le\xi<\omega_1$, then $\xi$ is countably infinite, so we can simply take $f_\xi:\omega\to\xi$ to be any bijection.
>
> For each $\alpha<\omega_1$ and $n<\omega$ let $A_{\alpha,n}=\{\xi<\omega_1:f_\xi(n)=\alpha\}$. This is the key trick, and you’ll probably have to stare at it a bit to get any kind of feel for why it works. Fortunately, merely checking that it works is easier.
>
> First, these sets $A_{\alpha,n}$ are clearly subsets of $\omega_1$.
>
> Now let’s look at two of them in the same column, say $A_{\alpha,n}$ and $A_{\beta,n}$, where $\alpha,\beta<\omega_1$. Suppose that some $\xi\in A_{\alpha,n}\cap A_{\beta,n}$; then by definition $f_\xi(n)=\alpha$ and $f_\xi(n)=\beta$, which is obviously possible only if $\alpha=\beta$. Thus, the sets in any column of the matrix are indeed pairwise disjoint.
>
> Finally, consider the sets in one row, say row $\alpha$: we need to show that $\omega_1\setminus\bigcup_{n<\omega}A_{\alpha,n}$ is countable. Suppose that $\xi<\omega_1$ is *not* in any of the sets $A_{\alpha,n}$ with $n<\omega$. That means that for each $n<\omega$ we have $f_\xi(n)\ne\alpha$. Recall how we chose the function $f_\xi$: $\xi\subseteq\operatorname{ran}f_\xi$, which means that for each $\gamma<\xi$ there is an $n<\omega$ such that $f_\xi(n)=\gamma$. Thus, if $\xi\notin\bigcup_{n<\omega}A_{\alpha,n}$, then $\alpha\not<\xi$, i.e., $\xi\le\alpha$. Thus, $\omega_1\setminus\bigcup_{n<\omega}A_{\alpha,n}\subseteq\alpha+1=\{\xi:\xi\le\alpha\}$, which is clearly a countable set.

This completes the proof that $\{A_{\alpha,n}:\alpha<\omega_1\text{ and }n<\omega\}$ is an Ulam matrix. $\dashv$

To get any more insight than that, you probably have to look at an argument or two actually *using* an Ulam matrix to prove a result.

Comment: Thank you, extremely insightful as always!

Comment: @user2034: You’re welcome!